# Handle boolean response and error in right way - Angular 6

Tags: angular

Below is my code. I am not sure whether my implemenation is right.

Service returns boolean value. What if the subscribe returns error?

```
this._service
  .UpdatesStatus(this.transaction)
  .subscribe((response: boolean) => {
    if (response) {
      this._notificationService.success('Accepted.', 'Accepted');

    } else {
      this._notificationService.error(
        'Failed.',  'Failed'
      );
    }
  }, (error) => {
    this._logrovider.error(error.message);
  }, () => {
    this._loaderService.isLoading(false);
  });
```

Comment: that is completely up to you to decide. If the request executes successfully but the server code returns false for the response, you can handle it one way, but if the request does not execute correctly you handled it a different way by logging the error it appears. is this what you want to do? its up to you

Answer (score 1):

If the request processes successfully, It will either return true or false.
And it depends on your server if it returns false for error.

But if there are some errors that are not handled by the server or may cause server error, they will be handled by error block of subscribe

```
(error) => {
  this._logrovider.error(error.message);
}
```